# Position an UIImageView over another with scaling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Is there a method on `UIImageView` that tells me the position of its image within its bounds?  Say I have an image of a car, like this:

[image: car with missing wheel]

This image is 600x243, and, where the rear wheel should be, there's a hole which is 118,144,74,74 (x,y,w,h).

I want to let the user see different rear wheel options, and I have a few wheel images to choose from (all square, so they are easily scaled to match the hole in the car).

I wanted to place the car image in a `UIImageView` whose size is arbitrary based on layout, and I wanted to see the whole car at the natural aspect ratio.   So I set the image view's content mode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`, and that worked great.

For example, here's the car in an imageView that is 267x200:

[image]

I think doing this scaled the image from w=600 to w=267, or, by a factor of 267/600=0.445, and (I think) that means that the height changed from 200 to 200*0.445=89.  And I think it's true that the hole was scaled by that factor, too

But I want to add a `UIImageView` subview to show the wheel, this is where I get confused.  I know the image size, I know the imageView size, and I know the hole frame in terms of the original image size.  How do I get the hole frame after the image is scaled?

I've tried something like this:

1. determine the position of the car image in its `UIImageView`.  That's something like:

   ```
   float ratio=carImage.width/carImageView.frame.size.width;  // 0.445
   CGFloat yPos=(carImageView.frame.size.height-carImage.height)/2;  // there should be a method for this?
   ```
2. determine the scaled frame of the hole:

   ```
   CGFloat holeX = ratio*118;
   CGFloat holeY = yPos + ratio*144;
   CGFloat holeEdge = ratio*74;
   CGRect holeRect = CGRectMake(holeX,holeY,holeEdge,holeEdge);
   ```

But there must be a better way. These calculations (if they are right) are only right for a car image view that is *taller* than the car.  The code needs to be different if the image view is wider.

I think I can work out the logic for a wider view, but it still might be wrong.  For example, that `yPos` calculation.  Do the docs say that, for content mode = AspectFit, the image is centered inside the larger dimension?  I don't see that any place.

Please tell me there's a better way, or, if not, is it proven that my idea here will work for arbitrary size images, image views, holes?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to have the wheel images the same size as the car image, with transparency... and just overlay it over the car image with the same bounds. It'll save you a headache trying to work out the positioning manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution **(by far)** is to simply use the same sizes for both the car image and the wheel option images.

Just give the wheel options a transparent padding (easy to do in nearly every graphics editing program), and overlay them over the car with the same frame.

You may increase your asset sizes by a minuscule amount.. but it'll save you one ***hell*** of a headache trying to work out positions and sizings, especially as you're scaling the car image.

Comment: (a) now I need an aspirin from slapping my forehead so hard after reading this, but (b) the slight bummer this way is the extra data that will come from having to provide different front wheel images.  I think I'll use this answer, but out of curiosity, is the computational way I tried the right way if I didn't control the wheel images?  Is there any help at all for this in the SDK?

Comment: there's nothing I know of in the SDK that would help with this.. except *maybe* using a `CGAffineTransform` on the wheel `UIImageView`'s `layer`'s `transform` property, you could apply a translate and then a scale. But honestly I wouldn't trouble myself!