# Position a UIView over a UIImageView with scaling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I asked a question similar to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887582/position-an-uiimageview-over-another-with-scaling/34887933#34887933), and got an answer that I accepted.  My new problem requires a regular `UIView` to be placed over the image view, making the other solution unusable.  So, new question...

Is there a method on `UIImageView` that tells me the position of its image within its bounds?  Say I have an image of a car, like this:

[image: car with missing wheel]

This image is 600x243, and, where the rear wheel should be, there's a hole which is 118,144,74,74 (x,y,w,h).

I wanted to place the car image in a `UIImageView` whose size is arbitrary based on layout, and I wanted to see the whole car at the natural aspect ratio.   So I set the image view's content mode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`, and that worked great.

For example, here's the car in an imageView that is 267x200:

[image]

I think doing this scaled the image from w=600 to w=267, or, by a factor of 267/600=0.445, and (I think) that means that the height changed from 200 to 200*0.445=89.  And I think it's true that the hole was scaled by that factor, too

But I want to add a `UIView` above the image view (as a sibling), this is where I get confused.  I know the image size, I know the imageView size, and I know the hole frame in terms of the original image size.  How do I get the hole frame after the image is scaled?

I've tried something like this:

1. determine the position of the car image in its `UIImageView`.  That's something like:

   ```
   float ratio=carImage.width/carImageView.frame.size.width;  // 0.445
   CGFloat yPos=(carImageView.frame.size.height-carImage.height)/2;  // there should be a method for this?
   ```
2. determine the scaled frame of the hole:

   ```
   CGFloat holeX = ratio*118;
   CGFloat holeY = yPos + ratio*144;
   CGFloat holeEdge = ratio*74;
   CGRect holeRect = CGRectMake(holeX,holeY,holeEdge,holeEdge);
   ```
3. convert holeRect into the parent view's coordinate system to create the frame for the UIView sibling.

   ```
   [parentView convertRect:holeRect fromView:carImageView];
   ```

But there must be a better way. These calculations (if they are right) are only right for a car image view that is *taller* than the car.  The code needs to be different if the image view is wider.

I think I can work out the logic for a wider view, but it still might be wrong.  For example, that `yPos` calculation.  Do the docs say that, for content mode = AspectFit, the image is centered inside the larger dimension?  I don't see that any place.

Please tell me there's a better way, or, if not, is it proven that my idea here will work for arbitrary size images, image views, holes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks very much to @originaluser2 for helping me through this.  It turns out there's a one-liner available in the AVFoundation library:

```
// given an imageView and an image
CGRect imageRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(image.size, imageView.bounds);
```

`imageRect` will wind up as the rectangle that the image occupies in the imageView's coordinate system (since we passed the bounds;  passing the frame will solve in the parent's coordinates).

For my problem, I can now just scale the hole rectangle according to:

```
CGFloat scaleX = image.size.width / imageView.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat scaleY = image.size.height / imageView.bounds.size.height;
```

Since I have the imageRect's origin, the hard part is done, just add it:

```
CGFloat scaledOriginX = holeX*scaleX + imageRect.origin.x;
CGFloat scaledOriginY = holeY*scaleY + imageRect.origin.y;
```

And of course, scale the hole's width and height:

```
CGFloat scaledWidth = holeWidth*scaleX;
CGFloat scaledHeight = holeHeight*scaleY;
```

And that's the complete, corrected rect.

Comment: wow, that is indeed super obscure... the only function in `AVUtilities.h`. Interesting to know!

Comment: what is here holex and hole width ?

Comment: @KishoreKumar - they are defined in the question: the x position and width of the hole in the image that I want scaled to match the image auto-scale

Answer (score 1):

<del>Well like I said on your previous question, there's nothing convenient in `UIKit` that will calculate this for you, so you'll have to do it yourself.</del>

### Well, turns out `AVFoundation` has something to help you, but if you ever need the manual way for reference...

---

In order to get past the problem of your calculations only working if the image is being scaled down according to it's width, let's just add a quick ternary operator to compare the ratio's of both the image view and the image...

```
CGSize imageViewSize = imageView.frame.size;

CGFloat imgRatio = imageSize.width/imageSize.height; // The ratio of the image before scaling.
CGFloat imgViewRatio = imageViewSize.width/imageViewSize.height; // The ratio of the image view

CGFloat ratio = (imgRatio > imgViewRatio)? imageViewSize.width/imageSize.width:imageViewSize.height/imageSize.height; // The ratio of the image before scaling to after scaling.
```

This will allow the ratio to scale down both landscape and portrait images in the same image view.

Next, you want to calculate the image offset when it sits in the image view, after having `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` applied to it (the documentation doesn't say, but the image is always centred within the bounds of the `UIImageView`).

```
CGFloat yOffset = (imageViewSize.height-(imageSize.height*ratio))*0.5; // The y-offset of the image on-screen (as it gets centered)
CGFloat xOffset = (imageViewSize.width-(imageSize.width*ratio))*0.5; // The x-offset of the image on-screen (as it gets centered)
```

Next you want to calculate the origin and size of the sub-image (the `UIView` that you want to insert into the hole), using the values that you defined in your quesiton.

```
CGPoint subImgOrigin = {117.0*ratio, 142.0*ratio}; // The origin of the sub-image (relative to the origin of the image)
CGSize subImageSize = {74.0*ratio, 74.0*ratio}; // The size of the sub-image
```

Finally, you want to pass these values into your `UIView` (or `UIImageView` if you want to apply this to your original problem)

```
// Your wheel view
UIView* wheel = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){xOffset+subImgOrigin.x, yOffset+subImgOrigin.y, subImageSize.width, subImageSize.height}];
wheel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:wheel];
```

---

### Going Further...

You could implement this into a category of `UIImageView`, allowing you to calculate the rect in the image coordinates into `UIView` coordinates, from any `UIImageView`. I have added a category implementation into the full project available below.

---

**Full project: https://github.com/hamishknight/Car-Sub-Image**

Comment: Thanks so much.  It turns out there's SDK help in AVFoundation.  Kind of obscure.